# How to get this fade and slide effect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fade, slide

I'm wondering how I could make a fade and slide effect like on: http://www.apple.com/stevejobs/

It's a really cool animation and I'm wondering if this is possible with jQuery?

**Note: I already know how to fade in stuff. I use jQuery all the time. I want the effect where new comments/memories/thoughts drop down. It slides down and fades at the same time.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fading is just some CSS they applied on an element:

From messages.css (line 81)

```
#messages #messageContainer #mask {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 15%, #FFFFFF 92%, #FFFFFF 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
    pointer-events: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

and for the scrolling effect, it can be done easily with jQuery.

**edit:** the elements are not fading away, they're going behind an element which is a gradient from transparent to white

Comment: Oh I see. I just was in Chrome Dev Tools and I saw how a new element is added and stuff. Thank you for your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

## **[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Yy2xH/6/)**

Basically you have to set the element to "almost invisible" with an `opacity` of `0.001` to get the slide to function and then use `fadeTo` to bring it back into `1`, which is completely visible.

```
$(function() {

    $('#button').click(function() {
        // new element to be added to top of list hidden
        var $new_li = $('<li style="display:none;">New Item</li>');

        // make element "almost" invisible
        $new_li.css('opacity', '0.001');

        // add it to list
        $('.list').prepend($new_li);

        // slide the "almost" invisible element down 
        // (shifting all others down)
        $new_li.slideDown('slow', function() {

            //once done sliding, trigger fade
            $new_li.fadeTo('slow',1);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Very cool! Even though this isn't how Apple did it (they just overlaid a div with a gradient to make the fading effect, and used some JS to slide it down, which I learned from the answer from @Nacereddine.) This is an awesome jQuery code though, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what part of it you want!  jQuery can do all of it, some is harder than others.  Take a look into the [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and [fadeOut](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) methods.  The comments falling down a level can be done with the animate method.

Edited based on your comment on another answer:

You can grab all of the elements you want to move down then use the animate method on it.  Do the following:

1. Position all items such that the first one is hidden
2. Fadein all elements except the first one $(".selector:not(:first)")
3. Slide all elements down while fading in with the animate() method, the fade will be ignored for all visible elements
4. Load the next item where the first was, repeat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll do what @Nacereddine said, but this is a nice little tutorial. Thanks :)

Comment: all this is not needed, see my answer.

Comment: To be fair jondavidjohn, what I mentioned and what you coded is fairly similar, and both would work just as well.  Yours loads the element first then slides, mine gets one ready before the animation, and whereas yours slides then fades mine slides and fades at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery fadeIn effect

```
$(selector).fadeIn('slow', function() {})
```

http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ckTRh/

Comment: That only fades in. I know that. I know jQuery. Please wait a few seconds after the page loads and you'll see the slide/fade effect.